# Upgrading Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu

I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu Server following these instructions:

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade

But the command do-release-upgrade (as root) brings me:

```
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Failed Upgrade tool signature
Failed Upgrade tool
Done downloading            
extracting 'intrepid.tar.gz'
Failed to extract
Extracting the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

Actually running hardy.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there a problem with the network?  Can you do an `apt-get update`?

Comment: no absolutely no problem with the network

Answer (score 1):

Intrepid is an obsolete version of Ubuntu and its life finished in April 2010. Upgrading to intrepid is no right option.

Edit:

Since you are on Hardy, your next step should be Lucid (next LTS).
Your `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` is probably not set to `Prompt=lts` but to `Prompt=normal` instead, so it tries to select Intrepid and fails.

Set `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` properly and launch `do-release-upgrade` again.

Comment: I'm actually running Hardy. Intrepid is what the setup automatically chooses

Answer (score 1):

Step 2 of the official Ubuntu tutorial is misleading. Do not change the prompt to normal, leave it as is and it works.

It will work this way, if you are updating vom Hardy.